# A way to change @inheritDoc template for PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

PhpStorm provides automatic tagging of generated methods with `@inheritDoc` comment.

I do Drupal development and according to standards the comment should look like `{@inheritdoc}` instead of `@inheritDoc`.

Is there a way to change that template?

Comment: I do not think it's possible (it's hardcoded AFAIK). In the past it was asked to do the current behaviour -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-27864. Check existing tickets (e.g. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI?q=@inheritdoc) and consider filing new one if you cannot find existing one that matches your request.

Comment: According to the [PSR-5 draft](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#6-inheritance), behavior of these two tags are different thus they're not interchangeable. The usual tag is intended to inherit the whole doc block while the inline tag is intended to inherit only the description. Which standards do you refer to?